# Child safe water hose

Tags: gardening

Right now, I am using classical water hose outside of my house. But there is a problem: My young kids are playing with the hose and turning on the water.

Yes, I am also trying to solve this issue through parenting, but the kids are relatively small (4yo and 2yo), so the temptation is too big.

So, is there any gadget which would make it hard for kids to turn on the water to ease my situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use some muscle when you turn off the spigot.  At 2yo and 4yo, unless the kids are abusing anabolic steroids, it should then be a challenge for them to turn it on.

If that's not enough, the gadget you need is a lock for the spigot.

You can buy one that attaches to the handle, like this:

[image: Guard'n'Lock]

*Guard'n'Lock - Image Source: Amazon.com*

Or you can buy one that attaches to the spigot thread, like this:

[image: FaucetLock]

*FaucetLock - Image Source: Amazon.com*

Comment: Just a little note: Never underestimate strength of a kid determined to accomplish a task :)

Comment: I am going this route simply because losing a key is smaller issue than losing the valve :)

Comment: @PavelJanicek Sounds good.  Did you decide on a lock over the handle or over the spigot thread?

Comment: I decided for the lower one :) My faucet is being open by just turning the handle 90 degrees and the process is quite easy. Locking the thread should hopefully do the trick for long enough until I will be able to explain the kids how to play with water more responsibly

Answer (score 10):

### Remove the faucet handle

Many outdoor faucet handles do not need the center screw to operate.

**To remove the handle,** hold the handle with one hand to keep it from turning and remove the center screw holding it on. Save the original screw or nut to be reattached later and store the handle in a safe place that is easy to reach before you go outside.

**When you need to use the faucet,** simply fit the handle back over the stem so you can turn it on and off. When you are done, take the handle with you.

[image]  [image]

**<sub>Not all faucets work this way so your results may vary.</sub>*

Comment: And then try to remember where you hid the handle from the kids...

Comment: ... or where the kids hid the handle from you...

Comment: Flashbacks to my own childhood...